# What is the bandwidth limit of Github personal access token?

Tags: github, access-token, github-api

Is Github personal access token limited to a number of requests/hour or bandwidth ??
I only use it to deal with the private repos of an organization.. Is there any limit for that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate limits are described here in one GitHub Docs page: [https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/rate-limits-for-github-apps#:~:text=User%2Dto%2Dserver%20requests%20are,per%20hour%20for%20that%20user](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/rate-limits-for-github-apps#:%7E:text=User%2Dto%2Dserver%20requests%20are,per%20hour%20for%20that%20user).

It's not just PATs, but OAuth, PATs, and user/password authentication are counted together with 5,000 per hour:

> User-to-server requests are rate limited at 5,000 requests per hour
> and per authenticated user. All OAuth applications authorized by that
> user, personal access tokens owned by that user, and requests
> authenticated with that user's username and password share the same
> quota of 5,000 requests per hour for that user.

Comment: I am using a PAT created manually in Developer settings. Still it shows 60 requests only per hour. Any idea?

Comment: How did you find out it provided only 60 requests/hr? Through request metadata?

Comment: Invoked a user search endpoint with "Authorization Beare <PAT>". in response headers, there is a rate limit value.

Comment: It should be "Authorization: Bearer <PAT>".

Comment: yes, there is a  typo in my comment. It is "Authorization: Bearer <PAT>" and it still returns rate limit = 50  (it was returning 60 earlier, now it is returning even less i.e. 50)